# Accessing server via public IP gives Connection Refused

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routing, remote-access

I recently fixed up an old PowerEdge 1850 at my workplace. I did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04LTS Server, using XFCE4 as the desktop environment for remote access.

Accessing it via it's local IP while I'm on the network is no problem. I can access SSH and the Apache webpage just fine. 
The problem is, I cant access anything about it via it's public IP.

I've opened a port (9500) for it in my router (Draytek Vigor 2925n). 
When I try to access it through:

1) a browser (chrome) I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

2) putty gives `Network error: Connection refused`.

3) Running `sudo netcat -l 9500` then trying to access `xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9500` through putty shows I'm reaching the server:

```
SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.65
```

through chrome gives:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9500
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

4) `sudo telnet xx.xxx.xxx.xx 9500` gives `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`. It works for port 22, but I still can't SSH into the server.

5) `sudo ssh -vvvv  root@xx.xxx.xxx.xx` asks for a password I don't have. Same with the username I use for local IP SSH "babar". However, I believe that is the SSH for the router, seeing as I don't give a port.

6) `sudo nmap -p 9500 xx.xxx.xxx.xx` gives `9500/tcp closed ismserver`. This has me confused. If I open the ports on the router, nmap shows closed. If I don't open, the nmap shows filtered.

I'm quite sure this is a router problem as this is with a clean install and should be relatively straightforward. But any help troubleshooting and getting to the bottom of this would help.

Comment: Nothing is listening.

Comment: What do you mean nothing is listening? Do you mean the server itself isn't listening to the port? If so What command makes it listen. EDIT: I saw the similar question. I'll try that tomorrow and update if necessary.

Comment: I went full retard. In my router port redirection wasn't working so I opened ports instead. Today I realized I was redirecting to 198.xxx.x.xx instead of 192.xxx.x.xx. Everything is fine there are no problems...